# Scalatra Mongodb not working mongoController not in package example?

Tags: scalatra

I am trying to add MongoDB support to my scalatra. Inside ScalatraBootstrap.scala I have the following code:

```scala
import org.scalatra._
import javax.servlet.ServletContext
import org.mongodb.scala.MongoClient
import org.scalatra.example.MongoController

class ScalatraBootstrap extends LifeCycle {
  override def init(context: ServletContext) {

     // As you can see, there's not much to do in order to get MongoDb working with Scalatra.
     // We're connecting with default settings - localhost on port 27017 -
     // by calling MongoClient() with no arguments.
    val mongoClient =  MongoClient()
    val mongoColl = mongoClient.getDatabase("mydb").getCollection("test_data")

    // pass a reference to the Mongo collection into your servlet when you mount it at application start:
    context.mount(new MongoController(mongoColl), "/*")

  }
}
```

and my build.sbt contains

```scala
version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.13.1"

resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeReleases

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % ScalatraVersion,
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra-scalatest" % ScalatraVersion % "test",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % "runtime",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.4.28.v20200408" % "container",
  "javax.servlet" % "javax.servlet-api" % "3.1.0" % "provided"
)


libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" % "2.8.0",
  "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-bson" % "2.8.0",
  "org.mongodb" % "bson" % "3.12.0",
  "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-core" % "3.12.0",
  "org.mongodb" % "mongodb-driver-async" % "3.12.0"
)


enablePlugins(SbtTwirl)
enablePlugins(ScalatraPlugin)
```

The error I am receiving is :
import org.scalatra.example.MongoController

Comment: object example is not a member of package org.scalatra

Answer (score 0):

Are you following this Scalatra documentation?
https://scalatra.org/guides/2.7/persistence/mongodb.html

Actually, `MongoController` is not provided as a part of Scalatra framework. You have to create `MongoController` in your project.